# How can I convert my virtual CentOS server harddrives from physical targets to VHD?

Tags: windows, centos, vhd, convert

I have a virtual machine running `CentOS` 5 on a `Windows server 2008 R2` with the `Hyper-V` role installed. The virtual machine has two harddrives installed that points to physical disks on an `iSCSI` target (see image below for details)

https://anonfiles.com/file/0c08492247344e60311bdc741e61497f

Now I would like to convert these physical disks to VHD-files. How would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a sysinternals tool for this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx